# How to switch between two multi windows in vim?

Tags: vim

Suppose there are 5 split windows in VIM.

How to switch between window 1 and window 4 quickly?

My current solution is: Ctrl W 3j   and Ctrl W 3k

Any other ideas?

EDIT:
Let's say window 1 and window 4 are two frequently used windows of 5 .
I want to switch from win1 to win4 and switch back, and vice versa.
need a shortcut for switching back.

Answer (score 2):

You can swap between buffers quickly using the buffers identifier.

If you have five buffers open and are currently in buffer 1 you can quickly swap to buffer four by pressing `c^w 4 w`, if you want back to buffer 1 you can do `c^w 1 w`.

This is the fastest one I am aware off at this moment.

Comment: Indeed a great solution, not known by most.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404246/546861) for a while until I realized having too many open windows sucked.